# HTTP Session Timeout with WebLogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic8.x

How do I find the HTTP timeout set on the WebLogic 8.1 application server?

Comment: What issue are you facing? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have Weblogic 9 and 10 available but on those platforms, you can go to the console, click on the name of your domain, then (in "Configuration" tab) "Web Applications". There you will have 3 parameters:

- Post Timeout: The amount of time this server waits between receiving chunks of data in an HTTP POST data before it times out. (This is used to prevent denial-of-service attacks that attempt to overload the server with POST data.)
- Maximum Post Time: Max Post Time (in seconds) for reading HTTP POST data in a servlet request. MaxPostTime < 0 means unlimited
- Maximum Post Size: The maximum post size this server allows for reading HTTP POST data in a servlet request. A value less than 0 indicates an unlimited size.

However, there might be other parameters involved depending on what your problem exactly is.